# control image size

Tags: html, css

I had re-sized the image to be suitable in my page by javascript but when I print the page , the images appear in bigger size , I tried to control the size of images in css , but they does not affected by it :

```
    @media print {

       img {

             width: 544px;
             height: 450px;

           }

    }
```

any one can help ?

Comment: Have you tried plain HTML? `<img width="544" height="450" src="..." />`

Comment: as i said I'm controlling the size in javascipt and the images appear in good size , but on paper after printing them they appear in bigger size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing your code to include the !important attribute.

```
@media print {

   img {

         width: 544px !important;
         height: 450px !important;

       }

}
```

and check to see if you are force-overriding it with inline CSS. the !important attributte is supposed to ignore any inline attributes but in my experience doesn't seem to work perfectly across all browsers. you can also change the sizes to be:

```
         width: 5.67in !important;
         height: 4.69in !important;
```

assuming a flat-panel monitor. you can find the converter [here](http://tiporama.com/tools/pixels_inches.html)